# Templates and nested type lookup

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a hierarchy of template classes implementing a CRTP like pattern. I don't understand why the name lookup fails in the lines marked with errors, and succeeds in the line marked "no errors here".

```
class CPublishedTypes
{
    public:
    typedef int published_t;
};

template<class Derived, class PublishedTypes> class Cbase: public PublishedTypes
{
    public:
        Cbase():ibase_(42){}
    private:
        published_t ibase_; //error: 'published_t' does not name a type       
};

template<class Derived> class Cmiddle : public Cbase<Derived, CPublishedTypes>
{    
    public:
        Cmiddle():imiddle_(42){}
    private:
        published_t imiddle_; //error: 'published_t' does not name a type    
};

class Cderived : public Cmiddle<Cderived>
{
    public:
        Cderived():iderived_(42){}
    private:
        published_t iderived_; // No errors here
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Cderived derived;
    return 0;
}
```

Using 'typename' doesn't help.

The C++ FAQ describes a similar but not identical issue here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-types.html

Cbase inherits publicly from PublishedTypes, which is a template *parameter*, but it's not a template *class*. So I don't see why CPublishedTypes::published_t is inaccessible.

Cderived inherits from Cmiddle which in turn inherits from Cbase. So I don't see why I don't need a typename to access CPublishedTypes::published_t  here.

What am I missing in the name lookup rules?

Comment: @templaterex: not quite a duplicate. Hassan Syed's example looks like the FAQ entry: he's inheriting from a template base class. I'm inheriting from a plain non-templated class which happens to be a template parameter.

Answer (score 3):

```
typename PublishedTypes::published_t
```

and

```
typename Cbase<Derived, CPublishedTypes>::published_t
// or simpler
typename Cmiddle::published_t
```

respectively, will work.

They're types that are depending on a template parameter (and can't be lookup up until the template gets instantiated) and thus need to be both qualified and prepended by `typename`.

Answer (score 3):

Types dependent on the template parameter need to be prefixed with `typename` and, in case of template base classes, the name of the parent class. In the last example, however, the class is not a template and this is thus not necessary as type lookup for `Cderived` is not delayed until template instantiation, so the regular lookup rules apply.